# ошибка 'str' object is not callable в bot.polling()

Tags: python, c, telegram-bot, telebot

Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Когда в телеграмм боте использую команду /add появляется ошибка **str object is not callable** к строчке **bot.polling()**. Функция бота - напоминать юзеру о делах , которые он отправит боту.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def in_text(message):
    time =  datetime.datetime.now()
    dt, dt_text = import_dt(message.text, time)
    text = import_text(message.text)
    if dt == 'null':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нужно указать время!')
    elif dt == 'old':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Это уже в прошлом!')
    elif text == 'null':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нужно указать о чем вам напомнить!')
    else:
        add_task(message.chat.id, text, dt, dt_text)
        answer = 'Я напомню тебе ' + text + ' ' + dt_text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling()
```

и внутрянка

```
def import_dt(text,timezone):  # Функция забирает дату и время из сообщения
  result = parse(text, tz=timezone, now=None, remove_junk=True,
               allowed_results=(datetime, None),
               default_time=time(12, 0), default_datetime=None)
  dt_text = result
  timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone)
  if result is None:
      return 'null', 'null'
  if datetime.now(tz=timezone) > result:
      return 'old', 'old'
  result = ('{:%H:%M %d.%m.%Y}'.format(result))
  dt_text = ('{:%H:%M %d.%m.%Y}'.format(dt_text))
 [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1] return result, dt_text


def import_text(text):  # Функция забирает текст из сообщения
  result = get_clear_text(text)
  if result == '':
      return 'null'
  return result
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точно так же работает и если указывать точно время *17:40*